# Wordpress with Phonegap speed concerns

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, cordova

I have a Phonegap application in both the Apple and Android market and have been getting some negative reviews in regards to the speed of the application. I have done many tweaks to my Wordpress site in an effort to decrease page load time, but there is still some lag while navigating.

My application makes a single JSON call on the first page of the application, which then 'launches' the Wordpress site. The reason I used Wordpress was to have the ability to update the pages from the Wordpress admin. It's just content right now, so there is no large images, etc.

What could I do better to speed up the Wordpress site? Or is there another solution outside of Wordpress to allow me to update the content inside the application without repackaging the app and submitting it?

Comment: Is the lag only on mobile platforms (slow networks) or does it show up on fast networks too?

Comment: I switched my hosting to WP Engine. Lightyears faster.